# C# FileInfo.Length Property for .txt file vs .csv file

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and new to Visual Studio. I am about half way through a 16 week class in C# using Visual Studio. I felt like I may have learned enough to understand this piece of code from work and modify it. So far I have been able to understand most of it (after many hours, and using google a lot). However, there are a few places that have me stumped... Or maybe the original programmer didn't use very good logic? I don't know... See the code below:

```
    //This is just a piece of the code... there are hundreds of lines of code above this
    private static void OnSizeChange(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // SET PATHS FROM WATCHER
            String filePath = e.FullPath;

            FileInfo infoForPath = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
            //CHECK FOR TEXT FILE IN ORDER TO VERIFY SIZE TO CONFIRM NEW EMPTY FILE WAS NOT CREATED
            String txtExt = ".txt";
            Boolean isTxt = e.FullPath.Contains(txtExt);
            //Length gets the size, in bytes, of the current file.
            if (!isTxt && infoForPath.Length > 5 || isTxt && infoForPath.Length > 0)
```

What you can not see here is that the file will either be a .txt file or a .csv file. My question is about the if statement.

What is the if statement checking?

From what I can gather, it is checking to see if there is a ".txt" in the file path && the length of the file in bytes is "> 5" (for a non .txt file) or "> 0" (for a .txt file).

What is the reason for the "5" and the "0"?

Is there some inherent reason for these numbers as pertains to .txt and .csv files?

If it helps, i found this code online, which is similar and could be used for testing I think from a C# command prompt application.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        const string fileName = @"C:\programs\file.txt";

        // Part 1: create new FileInfo get Length.
        FileInfo info = new FileInfo(fileName);
        long length = info.Length;

        // Part 2: print length in bytes.
        Console.WriteLine("LENGTH IN BYTES: {0}", length);
    }
}

Output

LENGTH IN BYTES: 60
```

Comment: Without knowing more about the setup, all we could do is guess - maybe an "empty" CSV contains a line with just 5 commas in it (e.g. 6 "empty" fields in the file)

Comment: By the way: I think this has a bug. "SomeFile.txt.csv" will be detected as ".txt" file, not ".csv" ... However, that _may_ be a "will never happen" case in your environment.

Comment: @ Fildor... Yeah... Like I said... It seems poorly written to me, but I don't want to judge since I basically have no experience. So... @ Damien... So... Five commas (Ie: 5 empty fields) would show up as 5 bytes?

Comment: I just tried something... This is probably not the right way to go about this... But I opened a new blank excel sheet and saved it as a .csv... It said the size was 1KB. I put a character in the first cell saved it again, it was still 1 KB... I realized it was rounding, the actual size was 3 Bytes... Just a blank .csv was 2 Bytes

Comment: ok... I opened notepad... typed 5 commas... saved it as a .csv... Its 5 bytes... I see what you are saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start `Boolean isTxt = e.FullPath.Contains(txtExt);` is error prone and not the best way to do this.

You should instead get the extension by doing `var fileExtenstion = infoForPath.Extension`
this will get you the extension of the file. For more info about this look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.extension?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_FileSystemInfo_Extension). Now that you have the extension you can check if the extension is .txt and return a bool or change how you're if statement works.

The reason for checking for the length of 0 for text files is because text files contain no data (length) when they are empty. I don't know for sure but CSV files may have a default length of 5. You can use the console app code you posted if you want to check this

Comment: My guess is... After some testing... and based on my knowledge of the .csv files I am working with, that Damien_The_Unbeliever was correct... It was probably assumed that the .csv file should have at least 5 fields or else there must not be anything useful in the file (ie: there is some problem with the file / basically empty).